# Pyspark orderBy giving incorrect results when sorting on more than one column

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Overview: I'm trying to sort a spark DF by multiple columns and  the resulting DF is only sorted by one column.

Expected result: DF with names sorted alphabetically within each company.

Toy DF:

```
l = [('Alice', 1,'funcompany'),
      ('Bob',5,'funcompany'),
       ('Jane',30,'Amazon'),
        ('Kenneth',2,'lameplace'),
          ('Dill',10,'funcompany'),
            ('Zeb',0,'lameplace'),
              ('Archie',50,'funcompany'),
                ('Debra',0,'funcompany'),
                  ('Vicky',24,'funcompany'),
                    ('Kanye',40,'lameplace')]

datis=sqlContext.createDataFrame(l, ['name', 'age','company'])
```

Sorting:

```
colss = ["name", "company"]

datis.orderBy(colss,ascending=[1,0]).show()
```

Comment: Try using a list of booleans instead of integers. Not sure if it'll help. Alternatively, just do `orderBy(F.asc('name'), F.desc('company'))`.

Comment: it's expected since there is no dupes/ties in the first column. sorting by the 2nd column only applied when the first column has the same values.

Comment: @absolutelydevastated  "datis.orderBy(F.asc('name'), F.asc('company')).show()" seems to give the same issue. Could you expand a little more using a list of booleans instead of integers? Thanks.

Comment: @jxc Just to confirm, you are saying that one cannot use "orderBy" to sort by more than one column?

Comment: no, you can certainly sort by more then one columns, but the first column in the orderBy list always take priority. if the order is certain by comparing the first column, then the 2nd and later are simply ignored. you can change the first 4 rows of your sample and set name all to `Alice` and see what happens

Comment: @jxc Nice call out, I tweaked my code based on your feedback and got the right result.So I think you get what kind of output I am looking for. You can submit the answer in code if you like so I can say you got it. I just switched the order of the columns I'm sorting by(company then name).

Comment: @DataDan, glad it helped, a post is not necessary as long as it worked. :) have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
```

and changing

```
colss = ["name", "company"]
datis.orderBy(colss,ascending=[1,0]).show()
```

for

```
datis.orderBy(F.desc('company'), F.asc('name')).show()
```

gives the desired result

Answer (score 0):

try with the below code

```
cols = ["name", "company"]
datis.orderBy(cols, ascending=False)
```